# Twitter bootstrap v2 and Jquery no conflict

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery

i m working on a website which uses an old version of Jquery (1.4.4), i can t update this version.
I want to add Twitter Bootstrap plugins. 
How can i use jquery no conflict with these plugins because they are interfering with others functions of the website using Jquery 1.4?
The pattern of bootstrap plugins is like this :

```
!function($) {
  // code here

  // plugin definition here

} ( window.jQuery);
```

Maybe like this ? :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min17.js"></script>

     <script>
     var jq17 = jQuery.noConflict();
     </script> 

     <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap-tab.js "></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var jq17 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

**Live Example**: http://jsbin.com/elomit/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: In which file those lines should be added to?